# Can scoreboards cause lag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can many scoreboard objectives (100+) cause tps drops (down to 4-5 tps)? I know in fact that command block systems on my server are what cause lag, bacause turning command blocks off in config removes lag, but I was optimising them for couple months now and I don't think that they can cause lag (most of the time there are like 20 /testfors running on observer clocks and all other blocks work of redstone, so they are not even "always active"). Scoreboards have various criterias (most are dummy) and used at different rates and different circumstances. Usually there are 20-30 people online but there are couple thousand players that have variuos scores.

Comment: *"most of the time there are like 20 /testfors running on observer clocks and all other blocks work of redstone, so they are not even "always active""* - The redstone will most likely be causing a lot of the lag. Try to switch over to repeating command blocks, and turn off TrackOutput.

Comment: _turning command blocks off in config removes lag_